# True or false? Any triangle we can $h_A^2+h_B^2 \geq 2h_C^2$, where $h_A, h_B, h_C$ are lengths of the heights from vertices A, B and C

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $\triangle ABC$ any triangle and the lengths of the heights from vertices A, B and
C are, respectively,  $h_A$, $h_B$ , $h_C$. Then how should we prove that,
$$h_A^2+h_B^2 \geq 2h_C^2, \quad h_C^2+h_A^2\geq 2 h_B^2 \quad  and \quad h_B^2+h_C^2 \geq 2 h_A^2$$

I think that is true but only I can bounded like this:
$$BC^2 \geq h_B^2, \quad AB^2 \geq h_B^2 \quad \text{By Exterior Angle Theorem}$$
So, $BC^2+AB^2\geq h_B^2$ and I can't prove that $h_A^2+ h_C^2 \geq BC^2+AB^2$

Comment: Please make subject lines informative about the mathematical content of the post. Please make posts that are more than just the statement of the problem you want people to solve for you.

Comment: Your question will not get answers and attract downvotes if you don't add what you have done to solve this problem

Comment: @Algebrology Thanks for your recommendations.

Comment: @FGF Now it's good :)

Comment: @FGF: How could it be true? If $h_A\le h_B\le h_C$ then
$$
h_A^2+h_B^2 \le 2h_C^2
$$
with equality if and only if $h_A=h_B=h_C$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a very narrow pointy isosceles triangle, with one angle close to $0^\circ$ and the others nearly $90^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

We may use following inequality:

$$h_A+h_b+h_c< a+b+c=2p\space\space\space\space\space (1)$$

Also:

$$h_A+h_B+h_C> p$$

Let's suppose:

$$h_A+h_B+h_C\approx p+\frac p2=\frac{3p}2$$

Squaring both sides we get:

$$h_A^2+h_B^2=h_C^2+\frac 94 p^2-3p\cdot h_C-2h_Ah_B$$

So we must show that:

$$t=\frac 94 p^2-3p\cdot h_C-2h_Ah_B\geq h_C^2$$

If $h_A=h_B=\epsilon$ then $p\approx h_C$ and we have:

$$t=\frac94 \times 4h_C^2-3 h_C^2-\epsilon=6h_C^2-\epsilon$$

So there is possibility to have a triangle in which:

$h_A^2+h_B^2\geq h_C^2$

But there is no guarantee for this relation to be symmetric. for example Consider Right angle triangle with sides 3, 4, 5 where :

$h_B=4$, $h_C=3$ and $h_A=2.4$ we have:

$h_A^2+h_B^2=2.4^2+4^2=21.76>2\times 3^2=18$

$h_B^2+h_C^2=9+16=25> 2\times 2.4^2=11.54$

But:

$h_A^2+h_C^2=14.76< 2\times 4^2=32$